# How to tell when the viewpager is done loading

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-viewpager, loading

I am using a `ViewPager` in my app.

My `ViewPager` is loading a lot of data and it is talking some time until it shows any content.
My question is this: How can I tell that the ViewPager is done loading (about to show its content on screen) so I can remove the loading progressbar?

Thanks!

Comment: how you load your viewpager?

Comment: What do you mean? I have an adapter that loads about 6 fragments because that I am preloading 6 pages with pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(6); thats why its taking time.
pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

Comment: @Luksprog: How would moving to a background thread helps me to know when to stop showing the progressbar?

Comment: My previous comment was incomplete. If the `ViewPager` is loading a lot of data then you're probably using some sort of background thread(one for each fragment). You could then see the background threads finishing and remove the `ProgressBar` when the last thread finishes its job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing your Progressbar on your adapter getItem() call back function when you are returning your last page Fragment :

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        Fragment InsantiatedFragment =  Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);

        if(InsantiatedFragment.getId() == 5) // your last page Id
        {
            //remove your progressbar here
        }

        return InsantiatedFragment;


    }
```